# Proving that $|\text{Cor}(X,Y)|=1$ only when $Y=a+bX$ for non-random $a,b$

Tags: correlation, random-variable, covariance

It is easy to verify the fact that $|\text{Cor}(X,Y)|=1$ when $Y=a+bX$ for arbitrary constants $a, b$. But how to go about proving this, without invoking steps from the proof of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form). Here is what I have done so far.

---

**My Attempt**:

Let $Y=g(X)$ and solving for $|\text{Cov}(X,Y)|=\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)}$ using $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{E}[XY]-\text{E}[X]\text{E}[Y]$, the following equality holds.

$$\left(\text{E}[Xg(X)]\right)^2-2\text{E}[X]\text{E}[g(X)]\text{E}[Xg(X)]=\text{E}[X^2]\text{E}[(g(X))^2]-\left(\text{E}[X]\right)^2\text{E}[(g(X))^2]-\text{E}[X^2]\left(\text{E}[g(X)]\right)^2$$

---

This equation seems over-complicated. How to go about proving that $g(X)$ is linear? Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I would use properties of the covariance on multiplication and addition of random variables

Comment: @Firebug Would you please specify the properties you are talking about?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks. Got the result, since the $\text{Var}()$ and $\text{Cov}()$ remain unchanged by adding a constant, $\text{Var}(aX)=a^2\text{Var}(X)$ and $\text{Cov}(aX,bY)=ab\text{Cov}(X,Y)$, so it is established that $Y=a+bX$.

Comment: According to some definitions of covariance, there's nothing to prove.  A *proof* must begin somewhere: with definitions and premises.  It's unclear what you're starting from because your question concerns the special case $g(x)=a+bx$ which by definition is linear.  Please explain what your starting points are.

Comment: @whuber I was trying to prove that $g(X)$ is linear. I did not at any point assume that to be true. All I said was that it could be easily verified that for $g(X)=a+bX$, this property holds, but I was trying to prove that was the only case in which it holds.

Comment: Your question currently asks (at the outset) how to "go about proving this," where "this" refers to the case "$Y=a+bX.$" In order for us to understand what you are trying to prove, you need the question to clearly state (a) what your premise is, (b) what the intended conclusion is, and (c) what definition of correlation you are using. If your intention is to prove $|\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y)|=1$ implies $Y=a+bX,$ you shouldn't succeed--because it's false.  One *can* prove there exist $a$ and $b$ for which $\Pr(Y\ne a+bX)=0.$

Comment: If you are trying to prove that $Y=a+bX$ implies absolute value of the correlation is $1$, then verifying $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=b^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=b\operatorname{Var}(X)$ is enough as mentioned by Firebug.

Comment: @Stubborn Assuming $b\ne 0,$ of course ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a good reason for the complications, because **the equivalence is not generally true.**  For it to hold, you have to assume $X$ has nonzero variance and that both $X$ and $Y$ have finite variances, and even then by assuming the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ is $\pm 1$ you can only conclude there exist numbers $a$ and $b$ for which there is a 100% chance that $Y=a+bX,$ not that equality holds everywhere.  In the other direction, you also have to allow that when $b=0,$ the correlation between $Y$ and $a+bX$ is zero.

The following account shows why these assumptions are needed.

---

Abbreviating $$\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}{Z}} = \sigma_Z$$

for random variables $Z,$ apply the relation

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \sigma_X\sigma_Y\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y)\tag{1}$$

to compute

$$\operatorname{Var}(\sigma_X Y \mp \sigma_Y X) = (\sigma^2_X)\operatorname{Var}{Y} \mp 2 \sigma_X\sigma_Y \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) + (\sigma_Y)^2 \operatorname{Var}(X).\tag{2}$$

---

Supposing $\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y) = \pm 1,$ relation $(1)$ implies

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \pm \sigma_X\sigma_Y,$$

which reduces $(2)$ to

$$\operatorname{Var}(\sigma_X Y \mp \sigma_Y X) = (\sigma^2_X)(\sigma^2_Y) \mp 2 \sigma_X\sigma_Y (\pm 1) + (\sigma_Y)^2 (\sigma_X^2) = 0.\tag{3}$$

At this point use the fact that when $Z$ is a random variable (like the one on the left hand side of $(3)$) for which $\operatorname{Var}(Z)=0,$ you can deduce there is a constant $\mu$ for which $\Pr(Z = \mu) = 1.$  (How you prove this fact depends on your definition of variance and whether you know relevant inequalities like the Chebyshev Inequality.)

**If you assume both $X$ and $Y$ have finite variances,** this proves there exist numbers $\mu,$ $\alpha = \sigma_X,$ and $\beta = \pm\sigma_Y$ for which

$$\Pr(\alpha Y + \beta X = \mu) = 1.$$

**If $\alpha = \sigma_X \ne 0,$** you can set $a = \mu/\alpha$ and $b = -\beta/\alpha$ and obtain

> $$\Pr(Y = a + bX) = \Pr(\alpha Y + \beta X = \mu) = 1.$$

Thus, it's not necessarily the case that $Y=a+bX,$ but when $\sigma_X\ne 0$ the chance that $Y$ differs from $a+bX$ is zero.

**When $\sigma_X = 0,$** you can use $(1)$ to demonstrate the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is not defined (because any number would work in relation $(1),$ which reduces to $0 = 0\, \operatorname{Cor}(X,Y).$)

---

Going in the other direction, when $Y = a+bX,$ just use properties of covariance to compute

$$\sigma^2_Y = b^2 \sigma^2_X$$

and (from $(1)$)

$$b\, \sigma^2_X = \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \sigma_X\sigma_Y\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y)$$

and solve for $\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y).$  The solution depends on whether $b=0$ or not.

---

Finally, **an interesting example of the distinction between two random variables being equal and just having 100% chance of equality** is the following.  Let the interval $[0,1]$ of real numbers with its Borel sets be the probability space and let $\Pr$ be the usual (uniform) probability measure on the interval. Let $X(t)=t$ (which obviously is a random variable) and define $Y(t)=X(t)$ when $t$ is irrational and otherwise $Y(t)=0$ (which also is a random variable).  $Y$ differs from $X$ on infinitely many numbers, but nevertheless the correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$ is $1$ and, indeed, $\Pr(Y=X) = 1.$